# How to determine the probability distribution function for such data?

Tags: statistics

I have data about a machine for 500 periods of time. During this period the machine stopped working 7 times - during the 40th, 145th, 200th,244th, 380th, 450th, 489th time period. 
How do I find the probability distribution of the random variable x - the number of registered problems, i.e. the number of cases in which the machine didnt work up to the current time moment.

Answer (score 0):

To estimate a probability distribution from your data, you need to make assumptions about the form of the distribution.

For example, you might assume that gaps between failures are independently exponentially distributed at a constant rate, in which case your distribution of failures up to a point in time would have a Poisson distribution.  If you took a failure rate of $\frac{7}{500} = 0.014$ per unit time then you might suggest after time $t$ you had for $n \ge 0$: $$\Pr(X=n) = \dfrac{(0.014t)^n}{n!}\exp(-0.014t)$$  or if you want to include the information you already have then for $n\ge 7$ and $t \ge 500$:
$$\Pr(X=n) = \dfrac{(0.014(t-500))^{n-7}}{(n-7)!}\exp(-0.014(t-500))$$

but if you made different assumptions then you would get different results.

Comment: I have plotted a histogram and made the hypothesis that it's exponentially distributed. When I ran a Chi-squared test for $H_0: \mu =70 hours$ against $H_0: \mu<70 hours$ I got P=0.07 at $90$%. Does it mean that my hypothesis can't be accepted?